# TypeError: Error #2007:

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex

I am getting this runtime error-

```
TypeError: Error #2007: パラメーター text は null 以外でなければなりません。
```

Parameters text is must be non-null
        at flash.text::TextField/set text()
        at Tile/refresh()[C:\Users\Makiko\Desktop\Michael\Games\New Project\src\Tile.as:68]
        at Tile/init()[C:\Users\Makiko\Desktop\Michael\Games\New Project\src\Tile.as:58]
        at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()
        at Main/tileform()[C:\Users\Makiko\Desktop\Michael\Games\New Project\src\Main.as:115]
        at Main/deal()[C:\Users\Makiko\Desktop\Michael\Games\New Project\src\Main.as:106]
        at Main/createtile()[C:\Users\Makiko\Desktop\Michael\Games\New Project\src\Main.as:86]
        at Main/init()[C:\Users\Makiko\Desktop\Michael\Games\New Project\src\Main.as:54]
        at Main()[C:\Users\Makiko\Desktop\Michael\Games\New Project\src\Main.as:33]

I can't quite an exact equivalent question.

I think this code is the source of the issue but how to fix it?

```
package {
    import flash.display.Sprite;
    import flash.events.MouseEvent;
    import flash.text.TextField;
    import flash.text.TextFormat;
    import flash.events.*;
    import excludespace;
    import Math;
    import flash.display.Bitmap;
    import background;
    import returncarrier;
    import tilecarrier;
    import Array;
    import flash.text.*

    public class Tile extends Sprite {
        internal var mode :String = "practice";
        internal var submode :String = "blank";
        private var setX:int;
        private var setY:int;
        private var IDlocal:int;
        private var kanalocal:String;
        private var valuelocal:int;
        private var kanafield:TextField;
        private var valuefield:TextField;
        internal var wordmultiplier:Array= new Array([[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,3],[0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0],[0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0],[0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0], [0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,3,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,3],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0],[0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0,0],[0,0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0,0],[0,0,2,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,2,0],[0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 3]]);
        internal var lettermultiplier:Array = new Array([[1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1], [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1], [1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 3, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1], [1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 1]]) ;

        /*[Embed(source="/../lib/meiryo",
        fontName = "myFont",
        mimeType = "application/x-font",
        advancedAntiAliasing="true",
        embedAsCFF = "false")]
        internal var japanese:Class;*/
        [Embed(source="/../lib/blank.png")]
        internal var blank1:Class;

        internal var checkstart:Boolean = false;
        internal var start:Boolean = true;
        private var blank2:Bitmap;

        public function Tile(ID:int,kana:String,value:int):void {
            IDlocal = ID;
            kanalocal = kana;
            valuelocal = value;
            addEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
        }

        private function init(e:Event= null):void {
            removeEventListener(Event.ADDED_TO_STAGE, init);
            blank2 = new blank1();
            this.addChild(blank2);
            addEventListener(excludespace.EVENT_START,refresh)
        }

        private function refresh(e:excludespace):void {
            var myFormat:TextFormat = new TextFormat();
            myFormat.size = 5;
            myFormat.align = TextFormatAlign.CENTER;
            //myFormat.font = myFont2.fontName;

            var myText:TextField = new TextField();
            myText.defaultTextFormat = myFormat;
            myText.embedFonts = true;
            myText.antiAliasType = AntiAliasType.ADVANCED;
            myText.text = kanalocal;
            addChild(myText);
            myText.width = 15;
            myText.height = 15;
            myText.x = 0;
            myText.y = 0;
        }
    }
}
```

In Main.as

Tileform shouldn't even run but it still gives an output. 
Now instead I get TypeError: Error #1034: 強制型変換に失敗しました。flashscreen_flash@44bbba1 を flash.display.Sprite に変換できません。
I failed to coercion . the flashscreen_flash @ 44bbba1 can not be converted to flash.display.Sprite.
    at flashscreen/init()[C:\Users\Makiko\Desktop\Michael\Games\New Project\src\flashscreen.as:23]
    at flash.display::DisplayObjectContainer/addChild()
    at Main/tileform()[C:\Users\Makiko\Desktop\Michael\Games\New Project\src\Main.as:153]
    at Main/deal()[C:\Users\Makiko\Desktop\Michael\Games\New Project\src\Main.as:122]
    at Main/createtile()[C:\Users\Makiko\Desktop\Michael\Games\New Project\src\Main.as:101]
    at Main/init()[C:\Users\Makiko\Desktop\Michael\Games\New Project\src\Main.as:69]
    at Main()[C:\Users\Makiko\Desktop\Michael\Games\New Project\src\Main.as:33]

```
                private function deal():void
        {

            trace(hand_current.length);

            for (var i:int = 0; i < (7-hand_current.length); i++)
            {

            var letterchoice:Number;
            var randomnum:Number;
            randomnum = (Math.random() * (1 + pool.length));
            trace (randomnum);
            letterchoice = Math.floor(randomnum);
            trace (letterchoice);
            hand_current.push(pool[letterchoice]);
            pool.splice(letterchoice, 1);

            for (var k:int = 0; k < 6; k++)
                {
                    trace(k);
                    trace(baseset[hand_current[k]]);
                    trace(basevalue[hand_current[k]] );}
            }
            }

            internal var tilearray:Array = new Array();


            private function tileform():void

            {
for (var i:int = 0; i < 6; i++)
                {var atile:Sprite = new Tile(i,baseset[hand_current[i]],basevalue[hand_current[i]] );

                atile.x = (i * 32);
             atile.y = 480;
             addChild(atile);
             tilearray.push(atile);
                }
             screen = new flashscreen();
             screen.x = 0;
             screen.y = 0;
             addChild(screen);

            }
```

Comment: Is that the code for "Tile.as"?  Please fix the markdown to make the error message and code more readable.

Comment: Is it chinese or japanese? I love how you just dump the error message in foreign language and expect any help.

Comment: Japanese but its just an error code really- giving a standardised unhelpful message no specific details.

Answer (score 2):

Error 2007 will occur when trying to set a property to a null value when it requires a non-null value.  I believe `kanalocal` is the null value.

```
myText.text = kanalocal;
```

Comment: `kanalocal` is being set in the constructor, but perhaps `kana` is coming into the class as `null`.   I'm pretty sure you are correct though as it's only thing in that method that could potentially be `null`

Comment: Basically, `text` can't be set to `null`, only a valid (incl. empty) `String`. If `kanalocal` can actually be `null`, then just modify the line to be `myText.text = ( kanalocal != null ) ? kanalocal : "";`